# how to set focus for last added ctrl in TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#

am using TableLayoutPanel to show the images.. here dynamically i ll add lot image into TableLayoutPanel .. here i need to focus the last added image .... i don't know how to do this please help me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can activate the last control by Control.Select() property.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using the Panel control to display the images and that your current code looks *similar to this:*

*in your OnLoad for the form...*

```
Panel panel=null;
foreach(Image i in images)
{
    panel =new Panel();
    panel.BackgroundImage=i;
    panel.TabStop=true;
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(panel);
}

panel.Focus();
```

- *With that code, the focus is never set correctly!*

**Why?**

It appears a form need to be activated before focus can be set.

With some minor tweaks the focus will set correctly

- first keep track of the last panel at the form level.
- Second override the forms OnActivated event and call panel.Focus() in there.
  It's still safe to construct and add inside the OnLoad override, or load event.